# Collateral Damage with non-lethal playthrough

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm playing through the game non-lethally, and I'm trying to save Malik. It's hard enough non-lethally since all the non-lethal weapons are single-shot slow-firing poor-accuracy, but I've got a problem that when the bot lands and I EMP grenade it, the explosion kills one of the attackers. Does that mean that I no longer qualify for the achievement?

Comment: Do you get "Man down" for his death?

Comment: No. I got Man Down and the other non-lethal thing when I knocked him out to begin with, nothing when he blew up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If enemy is hit by robot's self destruct explosion he is dead and it disqualifies you,but if he is hit by emp he will only be stunned and you still qualify as non-lethal.

Don't forget you can drag(E hold) stunned enemies away before the robot self destructs,you will have about 6 seconds.And be careful of exploding barrels.

Here's a video,it has some minor guidelines in description to help you.

Comment: Also, throwing a gas grenade at where the bot will land either knocks enemies out earlier (giving you more time to move them) or make them dodge away from the point of detonation (so that you don't *have* to move them later.) In addition, you can **throw enemies** too: Just start dragging them, aim, and "fire" to throw. Simple throws across flat ground and they live.

Answer (score 3):

If when you target the body it has a Skull instead of zz's then yes it disqualifies you from receiving the achievement.

Try to draw enemies towards you (and away from the robot) before throwing the emp.